# How to add ul and li classes to nav in wordpress

Tags: menus

I have this section in html bootstrap . i want to convert into Wordpress navigation.

```
<section class="mbr-navbar mbr-navbar--freeze mbr-navbar--absolute mbr-
    navbar--transparent mbr-navbar--sticky mbr-navbar--auto-collapse" id="menu-
     74">
    <div class="mbr-navbar__section mbr-section">
        <div class="mbr-section__container container">
            <div class="mbr-navbar__container">
                <div class="mbr-navbar__column mbr-navbar__column--m mbr-navbar__brand">
                   <!-- <span class="mbr-navbar__brand-link mbr-brand mbr-brand--inline">
                        <span class="mbr-brand__logo"><a href="#"><img class="mbr-navbar__brand-img mbr-brand__img" src="assets/images/discover-mobile-350x350-53.png" alt="Comp service"></a></span>-->
                        <span class="mbr-brand__name"><a class="mbr-brand__name text-another" href="#"><?php  bloginfo('name'); ?></a></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-navbar__hamburger mbr-hamburger text-white"><span class="mbr-hamburger__line"></span></div>

                <div class="mbr-navbar__column mbr-navbar__menu">
                    <nav class="mbr-navbar__menu-box mbr-navbar__menu-box--inline-right">
                        <div class="mbr-navbar__column">
                            <ul class="mbr-navbar__items mbr-navbar__items--right mbr-buttons mbr-buttons--freeze mbr-buttons--right btn-decorator mbr-buttons--active">
                                <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-another" href="#menu-74">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-another" href="#features1-75">About us</a></li>
                                <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-another" href="#msg-box3-81">HP OFFICEJET</a></li>
                                <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-another" href="#pricing-table1-86">HP ENVY</a></li>
                                <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-another" href="#testimonials1-88">HP DESKJET</a></li>
                                <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-another" href="#form1-89">HP LASERJET</a></li>
                                 <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-another" href="#form1-89">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul></div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: just search for `nav walker bootstrap wordpress`

Comment: can u provide me the correct link

Comment: `Walker` is the best way to make your items of menu. See the below link: https://www.microdot.io/simpler-wp-nav-menu-markup/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 3.0+, u can follow this:
https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Another reference link you can follow is this one:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-a-bootstrap-navbar-into-a-wordpress-theme--wp-33410

Usually, when you have an HTML menu (not talking about Bootstrap specific), its better to just generate the regular WordPress menu, than apply the styles you have on the original menu.